# Exit status of hive queries in .hql file

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

I have multiple hive queries in hive_queries.hql. I want to keep a log tracking the exit status of individual queries. Also if possible, I want to change the individual queries to fetch the data such as I want to change the query

```
"select * from ABC"
```

to

```
"load data local inpath '<path>/<folder_name>' select * from ABC"
```

Comment: I have added a possible solution. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep a log tracking the exit status of individual queries

As per my knowledge there is no standard way to track the exit status of individual queries being run through `.hql` file. What you may do:

1. Output your data in a hive table format.
2. Check for `_SUCCESS` file at the warehouse location/output location (if it is an external table or using `INSERT OVERWRITE`) to determine for failure.

> I want to change the individual queries to fetch the data such as I
>   want to change the query "select * from ABC" to "load data local
>   inpath '/' select * from ABC"

There is a trick to use `hiveconf` to achieve this.

Write your query like

```
`${hiveconf:start_tag}`
select * from ABC
```

By this way, basically you are creating a placeholder in the script which may be replaced at runtime. E.g.

if you execute the script as

```
hive -hiveconf start_tag= -f my_script.hql
```

Then your query will be executed as

```
select * from ABC
```

if you execute the script as

```
hive -hiveconf start_tag="load data local inpath '<path>/<folder_name>'" -f my_script.hql
```

Then your query will be executed as

```
load data local inpath '<path>/<folder_name>'
select * from ABC
```